# Join path impossible to solve

Tags: java, hibernate, join, hql

I have the following HQL query:

```
SELECT examen, OrganeSaisiMission
FROM com.an.eloi.model.domaine.amendement.Amendement as amendementOrigine 
join amendementOrigine.divisionExamen as divisionExamenOrigine 
join divisionExamenOrigine.examenOrigine as examen 
join examen.organeSaisi as organeSaisi 
join organeSaisi.texteDeLoi as texteDeLoi 
left join OrganeSaisiMission with OrganeSaisiMission.missionPlf.id = amendementOrigine.missionPlf.id and OrganeSaisiMission.organeSaisi.id = organeSaisi.id 
join organeSaisi.organe as organe
order by getTriBibard(texteDeLoi.texteBibard) asc, texteDeLoi.textePartie asc, examen.examenSecondeDeliberation asc
```

And I get an error:

```
2020-11-12 18:32:10,603 ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-1] -  Path expected for join! - at org.hibernate.hql.PARSER(reportError:56)
2020-11-12 18:32:10,607 ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-1] - [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@ad757a9 - at java.lang.Object(error:46)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.findSQLFunction(SessionFactoryHelper.java:364)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.IdentNode.getDataType(IdentNode.java:293)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.SelectClause.initializeExplicitSelectClause(SelectClause.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker.useSelectClause(HqlSqlWalker.java:857)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker.processQuery(HqlSqlWalker.java:645)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:685)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:301)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:244)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:256)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:187)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:156)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1770)
    at com.an.eloi.model.dao.examen.ExamenDAO.findExamensForMenuItem(ExamenDAO.java:161)
    at com.an.eloi.model.domaine.examen.Examen.findExamensForMenuItem(Examen.java:82)
    at com.an.eloi.service.transactionnel.grilleV2.moteur.Regles.checkAmendementsRedeposables(Regles.java:658)
    at com.an.eloi.service.transactionnel.grilleV2.moteur.Regles.processItemBoutonRedeposer(Regles.java:567)
    at com.an.eloi.service.transactionnel.grilleV2.moteur.Regles.executeReglesSelect(Regles.java:1222)
    at com.an.eloi.service.transactionnel.grilleV2.moteur.MoteurReglesMenuBarre.executeSelect(MoteurReglesMenuBarre.java:1222)
    at com.an.eloi.service.transactionnel.grilleV2.etat.SelectState.genereBarMenu(SelectState.java:63)
    at com.an.eloi.service.transactionnel.grilleV2.MenuService.executerBarreMenuService(MenuService.java:639)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy99.executerBarreMenuService(Unknown Source)
    at com.an.eloi.facade.grilleV2.GrilleSimpleFacade.executerBarreMenuService(GrilleSimpleFacade.java:181)
    at com.an.eloi.web.controller.barreoutils.BarreOutilsController.loadBarreMenu(BarreOutilsController.java:101)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:743)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:672)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:82)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:919)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:851)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.an.eloi.common.EloiActionFilter.doHttpFilter(EloiActionFilter.java:111)
    at com.an.eloi.common.EloiActionFilter.doHttpFilterSynchronizedBySession(EloiActionFilter.java:159)
    at com.an.eloi.common.EloiActionFilter.doFilter(EloiActionFilter.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.an.fwk.core.web.filter.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:84)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Obviously, Hibernate is not able to join between OrganeSaisiMission and the other tables. How could it be solved?

Edit: Here are 3 Hibernate mapping files which might be of importance

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- 
    Mapping file autogenerated by MyEclipse Persistence Tools
-->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.an.eloi.model.domaine.missionPlf.MissionPlf" table="mission_plf">
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Long">
            <column name="MISSION_PLF_ID" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="divisionDeLoi" class="com.an.eloi.model.domaine.divisionDeLoi.DivisionDeLoi" fetch="select">
            <column name="DIVISIONDELOI_ID" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <property name="missionPlfLibdef" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="MISSION_PLF_INTITULE" length="1024" />
        </property>
        <property name="missionPlfEtat" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="MISSION_PLF_ETAT" length="1024" />
        </property>
        <property name="missionPlfIntituleEtat" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="MISSION_PLF_INTITULE_ETAT" length="1024" />
        </property> 
         <property name="missionPlfOrdreEtat" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="MISSION_PLF_ORDRE_ETAT" length="10" />
        </property>
        <property name="missionPlfCode" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="MISSION_PLF_CODE" length="1024" />
        </property> 
        <property name="missionPlfOrdre" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="MISSION_PLF_ORDRE" length="10" />
        </property>
        <property name="missionPlfLigne" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="MISSION_PLF_LIGNE" length="1024" />
        </property>              
        <property name="missionPlfIntituleTableau" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="MISSION_PLF_INTITULE_TABLEAU" length="1024" />
        </property>                
        <property name="missionPlfOrdreTableau" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="MISSION_PLF_ORDRE_TABLEAU" length="10" />
        </property>

        <set name="amendements" inverse="true">
            <key>
                <column name="MISSION_ID" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="com.an.eloi.model.domaine.amendement.Amendement" />
        </set>
        <set name="programmePlfs" inverse="true">
            <key>
                <column name="MISSION_PLF_ID" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="com.an.eloi.model.domaine.programmePlf.ProgrammePlf" />
        </set>

        <set name="organesaisimissions" table="organe_saisi_mission" inverse="true" cascade="save-update" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="MISSION_PLF_ID" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="com.an.eloi.model.domaine.organesaisimission.OrganeSaisiMission" />
        </set>
      </class>
</hibernate-mapping>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- 
    Mapping file autogenerated by MyEclipse Persistence Tools
-->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.an.eloi.model.domaine.organesaisi.OrganeSaisi" table="organe_saisi">
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Long">
            <column name="ORGANE_SAISI_ID" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="organe" class="com.an.eloi.model.domaine.organe.Organe" fetch="select">
            <column name="ORGANE_ID" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <many-to-one name="texteDeLoi" class="com.an.eloi.model.domaine.texteDeLoi.TexteDeLoi" fetch="select">
            <column name="TEXTEDELOI_ID" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <property name="organeSaisiTypeDeSaisie" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="ORGANE_SAISI_TYPE_DE_SAISIE" length="100" />
        </property>
        <property name="organeSaisiLegisId" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="ORGANE_SAISI_LEGIS_ID" not-null="false"/>
        </property>
        <property name="saisieDebut" type="java.util.Date">
            <column name="SAISIE_DEBUT" not-null="false"/>
        </property>
        <property name="saisieFin" type="java.util.Date">
            <column name="SAISIE_FIN" not-null="false"/>
        </property>

        <set name="organesaisimissions" table="organe_saisi_mission" inverse="true" cascade="save-update" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="ORGANE_SAISI_ID" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="com.an.eloi.model.domaine.organesaisimission.OrganeSaisiMission" />
        </set>

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">


<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.an.eloi.model.domaine.organesaisimission.OrganeSaisiMission" table="organe_saisi_mission">
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Long">
            <column name="ORGANE_SAISI_MISSION_ID" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="organeSaisi" class="com.an.eloi.model.domaine.organesaisi.OrganeSaisi" fetch="select">
            <column name="ORGANE_SAISI_ID" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <many-to-one name="missionPlf" class="com.an.eloi.model.domaine.missionPlf.MissionPlf" fetch="select">
            <column name="MISSION_PLF_ID" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <property name="missionOrdre" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="MISSION_ORDRE" />
        </property>
        <property name="delaiDepotMission" type="java.util.Date">
            <column name="DELAI_DEPOT_MISSION" length="10" />
        </property>
        <property name="diffusion" type="java.lang.Byte">
            <column name="DIFFUSION" not-null="true" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

In the 2 first, I added the organesaisimissions Set, to no avail. I get the same error with or without them.

Comment: To reproduce your problem we should know related part of your entities mapping.

Comment: change all joins to explicit ones

Comment: @Conrad Aren't all my joins explicit?

Comment: @SternK I edited my question to add the mapped entities.

Comment: @AlexisDufrenoy What hibernate version and hibernate dialect do you use?

Comment: @AlexisDufrenoy I do not see the `com.an.eloi.model.domaine.amendement.Amendement` entity among of provided entities. Could you also simplify your query to the minimal that reproduce your problem. If you know that `order by` part and `getTriBibard` function usage is not related to the problem just remove it.

Comment: Finally, I rewrote the whole thing using SQL. The performance gain was pretty noticeable...

Answer (score 0):

You have to use aliases when you want to refer to some join. Apart from that, the exception suggests that the function you use is not mapped in the dialect. For such functions, you need to use the JPA function invocation syntax. Try this:

```
SELECT examen, m
FROM com.an.eloi.model.domaine.amendement.Amendement as amendementOrigine 
join amendementOrigine.divisionExamen as divisionExamenOrigine 
join divisionExamenOrigine.examenOrigine as examen 
join examen.organeSaisi as organeSaisi 
join organeSaisi.texteDeLoi as texteDeLoi 
left join OrganeSaisiMission m with m.missionPlf.id = amendementOrigine.missionPlf.id and m.organeSaisi.id = organeSaisi.id 
join organeSaisi.organe as organe
order by FUNCTION('getTriBibard', texteDeLoi.texteBibard) asc, texteDeLoi.textePartie asc, examen.examenSecondeDeliberation asc
```

Comment: The query I'm modifying is actually already successfully using that function, so I doubt that to be the cause of the error.

Comment: According to the stacktrace you are posting, you are apparently using a function in the select clause that is unknown to the dialect. The solution to your problem is similar to the answer I posted though.